# Clean Brew Rabbit Install js/tmpl/login.ejs undefined

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, homebrew

after I've been running on the RabbitMQ 3.8 for a while. It has been upgraded to 3.12.

I have an issue with starting the RabbitMQ.

undefined: There is no template at js/tmpl/login.ejs undefined

Running on Mac osX 13.4.1 installed through Brew.

```
brew install rabbitmq
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json

==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json

==> Fetching rabbitmq
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/rabbitmq/manifests/3.12.1
Already downloaded: /Users/hjalteniehorster/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/927544177389d9aa3811922f734e8469dddfbb55c3d30514b3e4053200e0f1e3--rabbitmq-3.12.1.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/rabbitmq/blobs/sha256:1bd4ecd0dda3b5a0740282d5dfb89979c0c6ddf680fa9d
Already downloaded: /Users/hjalteniehorster/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8175a968d5b14cf5bcff8df5c3a118a5fa0a32c30f632218c3b5428885488681--rabbitmq--3.12.1.all.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring rabbitmq--3.12.1.all.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Management Plugin enabled by default at http://localhost:15672

To restart rabbitmq after an upgrade:
  brew services restart rabbitmq
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  CONF_ENV_FILE="/opt/homebrew/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf" /opt/homebrew/opt/rabbitmq/sbin/rabbitmq-server
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.12.1: 1,438 files, 34.2MB
==> Running `brew cleanup rabbitmq`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

Other questions have answers that you have to restart your Linux server. Not sure if that works for Mac OS

***Update***:
Found this in some error logs.
Application rabbit exited with reason: {failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry,{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [article](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2022/07/required-feature-flags-in-rabbitmq-3.11/), some feature flags became mandatory in RabbitMQ 3.11.0. And they need to be enabled before updating RabbitMQ.

If they weren't enabled, one option is to downgrade RabbitMQ, enable the flags, and upgrade RabbitMQ again. But as far as I understand, only one version of RabbitMQ is available in Homebrew.

Another is to reinstall RabbitMQ (suitable in my case since I use it for testing on the local machine). Brew uninstall does not remove the folder where RabbitMQ saves its state. So it has to be done manually. In my case: `/opt/homebrew/var/lib/rabbitmq/`.

I found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/sx7Htl2Wpd4/m/v9NDDU2dAAAJ).